# C# - Recreating Battleship within a console app. Where do I call a method in this situation?

Tags: c#, console, console-application

The CheckInput() method works as it should and validates the user input is entered within the needed format (A1B1 or letter number letter number). Now I need to be able to check the ship length because almost all Battleship ships have different lengths. I want to separate this into another method that ensures the user is giving the correct length for a specific type of ship depending on where it's being placed on the map.

For example, D3H3 would be valid for the largest ship, a Cruiser, because it's 5 spaces long on the map. In this case, it would place the Cruiser vertically 5 spaces, on point 3, from point D to point H.

### The Issue

If the user has already validated their input past the CheckInput() method, then if their ship length is incorrect I need the user to reset what that ships initial placement is.

I know how to validate that its the correct length, but if its not, I don't know how to reset the original user input and make them input again, essentially going backwards through the program.

I made a method (CheckShipLength()) to check a specific ship type's length per user input.

1. If I call the method at the end of CheckInput() it doesn't work at all.
2. If I call the method after I call CheckInput() it only works once and then after checking the ship length one time, it will just move on to the next CheckInput() call.

Code:

```
public static class Dialogue
    {
        public static string placementInput; 

        public static string carrierPlacement;

        public static string battleshipPlacement;

        public static string cruiserPlacement;

        public static string submarinePlacement;

        public static string destroyerPlacement;

        //Sets each variable to user inputted coordinates. 
        //Example: A1A5 - where A1 is the coordinate of the stern and A5 is the coordinate of the bow. 
        public static void PlacementPrompt()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nEnter your ship placements below using the format 'A1A5'\n" +
                "where the first 2 characters represent the coordinate of the stern,\n" +
                "and the second 2 characters represent the coordinate of the bow.");

            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your Carrier's coordinates: ");

            carrierPlacement = CheckInput();

            //CheckShipLength(); works once and moves on to next line of code after attempting to validate once. 

            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your Battleship's coordinates: ");

            battleshipPlacement = CheckInput();

            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your Cruiser's coordinates: ");

            cruiserPlacement = CheckInput();

            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your Submarine's coordinates: ");

            submarinePlacement = CheckInput();

            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your Destroyer's coordinates: ");

            destroyerPlacement = CheckInput();

            Console.WriteLine(carrierPlacement + battleshipPlacement + cruiserPlacement + submarinePlacement + destroyerPlacement);
        }

        //Validates that the input given matches the needed format. 
        static string CheckInput()
        {
            char[] validInputs = new char[] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 't' };
            
            while (true)
            {
                //Get input
                var placementInput = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

                //Run validations
                if (placementInput.Length == 4 && Char.IsLetter(placementInput[0]) && Char.IsLetter(placementInput[2]) && Char.IsDigit(placementInput[1]) && Char.IsDigit(placementInput[3]))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    {
                        if (Array.IndexOf(validInputs, placementInput[i]) != -1)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry.");
                        }
                    }

                    return placementInput;

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry.");
                }
                //CheckShipLength(); does not work at all.
            }
        }

        //Validates that the length between one end of the ship to the other matches the ship types fixed length. 
        static void CheckShipLength()
        {
            //Horizontal length check
            if (carrierPlacement[1] - carrierPlacement[3] != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your Carrier's length is incorrect to its ship type, re-input ship coordinates.");

                carrierPlacement = CheckInput();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you make the returntype of `CheckShipLength` to bool and do it as long as it returns false? So you can call it at the end of your `CheckInput` but with a while.

Answer (score 0):

You could make `CheckShipLenth` to returntype `bool`. Then you could do this as long as it returns false. Your code would look something like this:

```
    static string CheckInput()
    {
        char[] validInputs = new char[] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 't' };
        
        while (true)
        {
            //Get input
            var placementInput = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

            //Run validations
            if (placementInput.Length == 4 && Char.IsLetter(placementInput[0]) && Char.IsLetter(placementInput[2]) && Char.IsDigit(placementInput[1]) && Char.IsDigit(placementInput[3]))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    if (Array.IndexOf(validInputs, placementInput[i]) != -1)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry.");
                    }
                }

                return placementInput;

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry.");
            }
            bool isValid = false;
            while (isValid == false){
                isValid = CheckShipLength(); 
            }
        }
    }

    //Validates that the length between one end of the ship to the other matches the ship types fixed length. 
    static bool CheckShipLength()
    {
        //Horizontal length check
        if (carrierPlacement[1] - carrierPlacement[3] != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your Carrier's length is incorrect to its ship type, re-input ship coordinates.");

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```